# USB ports restarting

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, kinect

I am working with a number of Dell laptops, all different models, and using the Kinect 2.0 for developmental reasons. However, while running the program, the USB port that the Kinect is suing will randomly restart, causing all sorts of errors.

I have already disabled USB selective suspend, with no results, and have even messed around in the BIOS to find some setting I can turn off (I disabled C-States).

The drivers are all up to date, and I have used multiple Kinects (we have like 7 hanging around in the office) and multiple laptops trying to see if it was just the laptop/Kinect that was bad, but all of them will restart the USB randomly during execution. This error doesn't even always come up, but only once every two or three executions...

How can I stop this random reboot?

---

EDIT: Not sure if this is related or not, but occasionally other USB ports, that aren't the USB 3.0 I am using for the Kinect will also shut down, sometimes for a second, sometimes until I reboot my PC. The Kinect will only shut down for a second or two however.

Is it possible that is a power supply issue? The laptops just can't draw what they need to run all the services that windows provides, along with sending info to the Kinect?

Comment: How long is the USB cable between Kinect and laptop?

Comment: @AliChen It's about 6ft, but that's also the only USB cable length Microsoft sent us

Comment: I did some poking around once for a similar problem (USB ports dropping, coming back up). With similar depth as you seem to describe, including USB diagnostics etc.It turned out to be a faulty mouse, possibly wiring related. Long shot, but if you have a second kinect you can try, or even alternate keyboard and/or mouse if those are USB, do so.

Comment: One other possible avenue: fingerprint biometric scanners are known to cause USB failures/lockups/repopulation loops.

Comment: @Yorik I have already used numerous different laptops and Kinects, and we don't have any Biometric scanners connected atm. They all seem to result in this reboot, I think because of the amount of "stuff" the USB port is pulling

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Kinect device has problematic hardware and software engineering.  Microsoft is not very strong, softly speaking, nor in hardware, nor in real-time software engineering. I used to work with first Kinects, I know. Problems are evident with V.2, it is clear from their own [sources](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/kinect-for-windows-v2-known-issues). You might want to try a good USB3.0 hub in between, it might alleviate signal integrity problems, but not bandwidth allocation software issues and real-time processing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update BIOS
2. Try a different port
3. Turn on the event log for USB events:

Event Viewer Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational event log

4. Download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff557573

5. Use USBView

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/usbview

OR

USBDeview
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

Comment: I did more than try different ports, I tried different laptops, but most of them only have the one USB 3.0
and there were no updates for the BIOS, already checked that.
Will try the USB View and look into WDK.Thanks

Comment: If the Kinect it is not compatible with your USB controller you might need a different platform. I would recommend trying it with a USB2.0 controller.

Comment: Kinect 2.0 only works with a USB 3.0, it is incompatible with lower versions. It does run for a bit, but not 100%